# How do i change copy right information of joomla website

Tags: php, joomla

I am working with a website using joomla it has copy right information on in its footer. I want to change the copy right information on footer. I gone through some tutorials they are saying that we can change the copy right information in at joomlas `includes/footer.php` But i am unable to detect such file in `wwww directory`. What should i do?.

Comment: check whether Footer module is enabled in Extensions->modulemanager

Comment: In www directory there is no Extensions folder

Comment: Iam saying in Admin section go to Extensions->modulemanager and see footer module is enabled?

Comment: If the footer module is not installed go to /templates/your-default-template/index.php At the bottom You will find info related to footer

Comment: When the client come to me he want two things One is SEO and another one is Changing credential but he dont know anything apart from FTP access.

Comment: @arunwebber - As mentioned already, login to your Joomla admin panel, then go to **Modules** (top menu) >> **Module Manager** and there will most likely be a Footer module. Open it and change the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be located in different places, but as mentioned by @Choco you should be able to locate a module by the name "footer" otherwise you can open the template editor (Extensions -> Template Manager -> Templates) and then open the template that you are currently using and open the file called index.php

In there you should look for the position that is located where the copyright is placed It should look something like this `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="none" />` and then you can find out what position your copyright module is located in.

Or perhaps it's hardcoded into the template, in which case you should look for it in the template index.php  file aswell